# Drawing a simple image in R

Tags: r, image, plot, draw

I'm completely new to R (from MATLAB). I'm trying to generate a rectangular image composed of several smaller coloured regions. It is basically a thermometer. It will sit in a transparent/white background, with room to the left for a line/arrow pointing to a certain colour, with a character string left of that e.g. "XXXX sits here".

I could do it in MATLAB without too much worry (new workplace uses R), I'd simply define a plotting area, fill the rectangles with particular colours to draw the thermometer, draw a horizontal line using a variable to tell me where on the thermometer it sits, then add a string with the name to the left of that. Then I'd save the lot as an image, or just send it to the template I'm working on.

I am struggling to do this in R (using R studio). Here's what I have so far:

```
require(grDevices)
## set up the plot region:

dev.off()
ACE <- par(bg = "transparent", usr = c(0, 51, 0, 451)) #make the plot window a certain size?

plot(x=NULL, y=NULL , type = "n", axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim=c(0,51), ylim=c(0,450)) #set up the plot?

#draw rectangles for thermometer
rect(0, 0, 50, 148, col = "#c00000", border = "transparent")     #red
rect(0, 148, 50, 225, col = "#ed7d31", border = "transparent") #orange
rect(0, 225, 50, 297, col = "#ffc000", border = "transparent") #gold
rect(0, 297, 50, 360, col = "#92d050", border = "transparent") #lgreen
rect(0, 360, 50, 450, col = "#00b050", border = "transparent") #dgreen
assign("ACE",  ACE)

#set up png
png(filename = "ACE.png",
    width = 5, height = 15, units = "cm", pointsize = 12,bg =     "white", res = 300,family = "", restoreConsole = TRUE,type =     c("windows", "cairo", "cairo-png"))
print(ACE) #send my plot to the png????
dev.off()
```

It plots the colours with the correct height in the "plots" tab in R studio, but seems to fill the whole plot regardless of me telling it what saize I'd like the plot. I'm not sure how to preview it either (a la imshow()). The png output is the correct dimensions though is empty.

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me, I've tried to do it solo for the last couple of hours and have only gotten this far.

Many thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to print in an image file:

```
#set up png
png(filename = "ACE.png", width = 5, height = 15, units = "cm", pointsize = 12, res = 300)
par(bg = "transparent", usr = c(0, 51, 0, 451)) #make the plot window a certain size?

plot(x=NULL, y=NULL , type = "n", axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim=c(0,51), ylim=c(0,450)) #set up the plot?

#draw rectangles for thermometer
rect(0, 0, 50, 148, col = "#c00000", border = "transparent")     #red
rect(0, 148, 50, 225, col = "#ed7d31", border = "transparent") #orange
rect(0, 225, 50, 297, col = "#ffc000", border = "transparent") #gold
rect(0, 297, 50, 360, col = "#92d050", border = "transparent") #lgreen
rect(0, 360, 50, 450, col = "#00b050", border = "transparent") #dgreen

dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! Any idea how to limit the rectangles to a small region of the plot, to allow for other things to be printed onto it (i.e. line and character string)?

Comment: It is dependent on what you add to your figure. You only asked for these rectangles.

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for helping me out Pascal, I should have showed more gratitude before I asked more questions.

Ideally there would be a white space equivalent to 2*width of the thermometer to the left where I can put some text and a line (i'm figuring those out now), I just can figure how to get that white space. Would I hame the plot 3* as wide, and siomply draw a white rectagle for the first 2/3s?

Comment: You should have a look at the `layout()` function. You can search for examples on Internet.